# procedure to insert columns from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i want to insert columns date, service and service_count from an existing table to a new table. i want to do it using a procedure but it's not working.

---

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROC  [dbo].[SP_INSERTCOLOUMNS]     
AS       
BEGIN
            DECLARE @SQLS NVARCHAR(MAX)

            SET @SQLS = 'insert into test(date,service,service_count) 
                                 select date,service,count(service) from tbl_OBD_CDRS 
                                 group by date,service'
            PRINT @SQLS

            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLS            
            PRINT 'INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY'
END
```

---

if i run the insert command independently it works fine. if i run it using this procedure it says Command(s) completed successfully, but no changes are made in the table "test".

Comment: are you trying to insert records or columns?

Comment: @shantanu - whole columns

Comment: can you join this room to discuss this issue http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50100/discuss-issues-in-procedure

Comment: Do you already have data, service, service_count column in Test table?

Comment: #shantanu - yes i have these coloumns

Comment: Can you add sp call as well. how you are calling. Also if you can join chat room, we can continue our discussion over there..

Comment: @shantanu- i clicked on the link , it says i need 20 rep points to talk there.

Comment: try to replace your insert query with any dummy query may be 'select 1' and see if its returning results. Also, make sure you are not running sp in transaction that is being rolled back later.

Comment: @shantanu- nope.. not working.. i came to know taht i have to declare variables for it, can you explain how to do it.

Comment: You need not pass variable as `sp_executesql [ @stmt = ] statement` where square brackets means an optional parameter. Now the thing is if you were able to see `1` in an output when you changed your query. Also did you check if there are records present in `tbl_OBD_CDRS` table

Comment: @shantanu, there are records in tbl_OBD_CDRS

Comment: actually i'm new to sql so didn't know that it was not executing, it was only compiling.

this worked>>>  EXEC [dbo].[SP_INSERTCOLOUMNS]

Comment: cool...I mentioned that...:)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in your script. Why don't you try to check count in Test table. See if no of records increases in your Test table.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROC  [dbo].[SP_INSERTCOLOUMNS]     
AS       
BEGIN
            select date,service,count(service) from tbl_OBD_CDRS 
                                 group by date,service

            DECLARE @SQLS NVARCHAR(MAX)

            SET @SQLS = 'insert into test(date,service,service_count) 
                                 select date,service,count(service) from tbl_OBD_CDRS 
                                 group by date,service'
            PRINT @SQLS

            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLS            
            PRINT 'INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY'
END
```

Try to run this on SQL Server and post your result.

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_INSERTCOLOUMNS]
```

Comment: test table is empty. there are no records in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROC  [dbo].[SP_INSERTCOLOUMNS]     
AS       
BEGIN
           -- select date,service,count(service) from tbl_OBD_CDRS 
               --                  group by date,service



            insert into test(date,service,service_count) 
            select date,service,count(service) from tbl_OBD_CDRS Group by date,service


            PRINT 'INSERTED SUCCESSFULLY'
END
```

use this if any error in table / datatype it throw directly